# following a tutorial notfoundhttpexception

Tags: exception, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

i am pretty new to framework and laravel in general, im struggling to learn laravel, and i have found this book.

https://leanpub.com/learninglaravel

I hope is a good start. (usually i coded in php and html)

I have a problem following the basic tutorial (:/ not a good start lol)

**Routes.php**

```
Route::post('contact', function()
{

$data = Input::all();
$rules = array(
'subject' => 'required',
'message' => 'required'
);
$validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);


 if($validator->fails()) {
 return Redirect::to('contact')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
 }
 return 'Your message has been sent';

 });



Route::get('/', function()
{
return View::make('home');
});
Route::get('about', function()
 {
return View::make('about');
});
```

Contact.blade.php

```
@extends('layout')
@section('content')
<h1>Contact Us.</h1>
<p>Please contact us by sending a message using the form below:</p>
{{ HTML::ul($errors->all(), array('class'=>'errors'))}}

{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'contact')) }}
{{ Form::label('Subject') }}
{{ Form::text('subject','Enter your subject') }}
<br />
{{ Form::label('Message') }}
{{ Form::textarea('message','Enter your message') }}
<br />
{{ Form::submit() }}
{{ Form::close() }}
 @stop
```

THe other pages works well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need another route to display the contact form page

```
Route::get('contact', function() {

    return View::make('contact');

});
```

Comment: i am crying now, how can someone learn laravel when never used any framework and just go with plain php? Im panicking coz i need to finish a website in a month or so. any hints?

Comment: Is laravel a requirement to build the website? If not you should probably look at a CMS (e.g. Joomla) which offers most of the basic (and not only) functionality out of the box. Good luck!

Comment: actually the website is very customized and need to use a product database

Comment: In case you haven't discovered it yet, take a look [here](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch). I believe it will help you.